# Swift: CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h file not found when importing through Bridging-Header file

Tags: swift, core-plot, bridging-header

I'm iOS beginner, so I'm sorry if this is an elementary mistake...

Hi, I'm developing iOS app by Swift, and trying to use CorePlot( https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot ) Library.

Using examples from this blog ( http://blog.alwold.com/2014/08/07/using-coreplot-with-swift-in-ios/ ), I tried following procedures.

---

1. pod install CorePlot.
2. make Bridging-Header file.
3. import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h in Bridging-Header file.
4. register Bridging-Header.h to app target Objective-C Bridging-Header.

---

But I got following error when running app.

*Bridging-Header.h*

`'CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h' file not found.`

Searching the file existence, I found `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h` in `Users/USER_NAME/Document/workspace/PROJECT_NAME/Pods/CorePlot/framework/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h`.

How can I deal with this?
If you need additional information, please tell me.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried #import "CorePlot/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h" ?

Comment: in Relese notes it was deprecated

Comment: The Core Plot static library is not deprecated in 2.0, only the separate project file.

Answer (score 0):

In the application build settings, make sure the header search paths include the framework directory.

Also, until Core Plot 2.0 is released, be sure to point your podfile at the "release-2.0" branch. It has several API changes to make Core Plot work with Swift

Comment: how to add coreplot 2.0 in briginging header

Comment: getting these error when im using coreplot 2.0 Failed to import bridging header '/Users/ramkumar/Desktop/LIVE_PROJECTS/Sample/Sample-Bridging-Header.h'

Comment: @Ramkumarchintala Ask a new question with details about your setup and the problem you're having. Adding comments to an old question is not helpful and doesn't give enough information for us to help you.

Comment: I dont have Permissions to post a question. i just add the pod file and install pods .open workspace and created Bridging header in that header #import "coreplot.h"  and in my view controller import CorePlot . it gives errors in coreplot.h file "Cocoa/CoCoa.h" not found

Comment: @Ramkumarchintala Make sure your pod file specifies the correct platform. The Cocoa framework is available only on the Mac.

Comment: can u sand me the sample application(or) link coreplot 2.0 with swift xcode 7.1

Comment: The example code is included in the release package and at https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/tree/master/examples.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the similar issue with Xcode 10 beta 6. Problem is that part of the framework we have mac supported cocoa files which are not available for iOS. So we just need to remove them to make it work for iOS.

[image]